# Unable to run React Native app when integrating React Native Navigation

Tags: android, react-native, react-native-navigation, wix-react-native-navigation

I followed the steps on the official [Wix React Native Navigation documentation](https://wix.github.io/react-native-navigation/#/installation-android) to integrate it on android.

But after making the necessary changes, I'm getting this error when I try to run the app :

```
FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

Execution failed for task ':app:transformNative_libsWithMergeJniLibsForDebug'.
    > java.io.IOException: Could not delete path 'C:\Users\PathToProject\android\app\build\intermediates\transforms\mergeJniLibs\debug\folders'.
```

I don't know how to debug this error. How do I fix it?

Answer (score 0):

delete your app>build folder of the project
and 
do 
**react-native run-android**